# QuantLib: Modeling GBP-6M-Libor Fixed-Float swaps as valuation date after 2021-12-31 using QuantLib

Tags: programming, quantlib

Starting from January 2022, LIBOR fixings/rates for most currencies (GBP, EUR, CHF, JPY) will be discontinued. After the switching date 2021-12-31 , such floating-rate bonds will effectively have two kinds of coupons; those until 2021, and those fixed afterwards. The library doesn’t provide a constructor for such valuations. I can compute Fixed-Float NPV for the valuation date before 2021-12-31 but what is the best way to compute Fixed-Float NPV by keeping valuation date after 2021-12-31. Please provide any example.

Comment: I can't speak for Quantlib and what classes/constructors exist for this type of so-called **fallback** swap. The LIBORs after Jan 1, 22 are to be replaced by x-month compound versions of the respective overnight riskfree rate (SONIA, ESTR, SARON, TONAR), plus the ISDA-defined fallback spread (= historical median spread between LIBOR and the RFRs). This makes the valuation of your swap after Dec 31 akin to a OIS (overnight indexed swap), with the additional complexity of a (dynamic) observation shift, which you apply to the accrual period in order to keep the original swap's payment structure.

Comment: @KevinT Thanks for the reply. This seems it more complex after the Libor transition. Do you have ready FixedFloat example to see the methodology using quantlib. It will be very helpful.

Comment: It's really not that complex and in fact it's a reality for almost half a year now in 2022. *As indicated, I don't know about Quantlib* (there might be others here at QSE though...) - but the crucial concepts for you to understand are **(a)** compounded overnight rates and the valuation of OIS, **(b)** the [ISDA fallback rule book](https://data.bloomberglp.com/professional/sites/10/IBOR-Fallback-Rate-Adjustments-Rule-Book.pdf), **(c)** the (dynamic) backward observation shift. If you have a more specific question on any of those, please do feel free to ask.